# Gradlew Printing Control Characters with Git Bash

Tags: git-bash

I am using git-bash as Integrated terminal in Intellij Idea Community Edition(2020).
The Gradlew Downloaded is 5.2.1

When I run something like
`gradlew build`

It prints some random text like the screenshot attached.
[image]

Initially I thought it has something to do with gradlew but then I tried building using CMD from Explorer
it worked prefectly.

Then I even tried to build it with git-bash from Explorer and it worked.
I tried using CMD as Integrated Terminal in IntelliJ and it worked with CMD as well.

I am not able to figure out what is wrong with git-bash and IntelliJ combination
Any Help will be appreciated.

EDIT 1:
Downgrading Git-bash for windows from 2.28.0 to 2.26.2 worked for me.
Removing IntelliJ tag from Question.

I think there has to be some problem with git-bash 2.28.0

Comment: The same problem occurs if you run sh.exe and gradle help in it outside of IntelliJ IDEA, so it's not IDE specific problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-247532

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This started happening to me in VSCode and IntelliJ when i recently updated Git, I reverted to an older version of Git and it went away. I did notice they made some updates to the bash shell.

Using `TERM=cygwin ./gradlew build` resolved the issue in both those environments for me.

Comment: Doesn't work. This completely destroys the functionality of Git Bash. For example it interprets backspace as if I typed space instead.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I was just offering a suggestion to fixing the problem with gradlew control characters. I only use this as a one off when I have to use gradlew not as a permanent solution to fix all of mingw64's issues with control characters ;( There are other shells you could use, in fact you could use windows terminal or install cygwin64 and run it's bash shell directly.

Comment: After months of experiencing this problem within Visual Studio Code, this solution worked for me, backspace and everything else is still working as expected. I've added "export TERM=cygwin" to ~/.bashrc and everything is working again.

Comment: Similar idea as scharette, except I added it to ~/.bash_profile, which Git Bash (in Git for Windows) is reading at startup.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks @docslax. This is how I fixed it on Android Studio.

[image: Android Studio Settings]