# git bash terminal output suddenly unreadable (during gradle builds)

Tags: bash, git, encoding, terminal, formatting

I noticed today that using git bash, the output from gradle builds started dumping some strange hex garbage that is impossible to read. I'm not sure if it's an encoding issue or what changed, but I can't seems to figure out what went awry. If I run the same build on WSL or a linux box the formatting is fine. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$ git version
 git version 2.31.1.windows.1
```

```
./gradle clean buildPackage
...
[2A[1m<[0;32;1m============[0;39;1m-> 93% EXECUTING [37m 41s][m[39D[1B[1m> :dkrcont-
package:buildPackage[m[36D[1B[2A[1m<[0;32;1m============[0;39;1m-> 93% EXECUTING [37m 
41s][m[39D[1B[1m> :dkrcont-
package:buildPackage[m[36D[1B[2A[1m<[0;32;1m============[0;39;1m-> 93% EXECUTING [37m 
41s][m[39D[1B[1m> :dkrcont-
package:buildPackage[m[36D[1B[2A[1m<[0;32;1m============[0;39;1m-> 93% EXECUTING [37m 
41s][m[39D[1B[1m> :dkrcont-
package:buildPackage[m[36D[1B[2A[1m<[0;32;1m============[0;39;1m-> 93% EXECUTING [37m 
41s][m[39D[1B[1m> :dkrcont-
package:buildPackage[m[36D[1B[2A[1m<[0;32;1m============[0;39;1m-> 93% EXECUTING [37m 
41s][m[39D[1B[1m> :dkrcont-
package:buildPackage[m[36D[1B[2A[1m<[0;32;1m============[0;39;1m-> 93% EXECUTING [37m 
41s][m[39D[1B[1m> :dkrcont-
package:buildPackage[m[36D[1B[2A[1m<[0;32;1m============[0;39;1m-> 93% EXECUTING [37m 
41s][m[39D[1B[1m> :dkrcont-
package:buildPackage[m[36D[1B[2A[1m<[0;32;1m============[0;39;1m-> 93% EXECUTING [37m 
41s][m[39D[1B[1m> :dkrcont-
package:buildPackage[m[36D[1B[2A[1m<[0;32;1m============[0;39;1m-> 93% EXECUTING [37m 
41s][m[39D[1B[1m> :dkrcont-
package:buildPackage[m[36D[1B[2A[1m<[0;32;1m============[0;39;1m-> 93% EXECUTING [37m 
42s][m[39D[1B[1m> :dkrcont-
package:buildPackage[m[36D[1B[2A[1m<[0;32;1m============[0;39;1m-> 93% EXECUTING [37m 
42s][m[39D[1B[1m> :dkrcont-
package:buildPackage[m[36D[1B[2A[1m<[0;32;1m============[0;39;1m-> 93% EXECUTING [37m 
42s][m[39D[1B[1m> :dkrcont-
package:buildPackage[m[36D[1B[2A[1m<[0;32;1m============[0;39;1m-> 93% EXECUTING [37m 
42s][m[39D[1B[1m> :dkrcont-
package:buildPackage[m[36D[1B[2A[1m<[0;32;1m============[0;39;1m-> 93% EXECUTING [37m
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63789294/gradlew-printing-control-characters-with-git-bash may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow I was using /bin/bash.exe in lieu of git-bash.exe.  Even though I didn't find a "fix" per se, switching binaries solved my issue.  AFAIK the /bin/* executables aren't guaranteed to be supported/backwards compatible anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Your gradle is outputting ANSI color sequences which your terminal doesn't interpret.

If you're on Windows 10 and use the windows console, you *may* have to enable virtual terminal ANSI sequence :

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
"VirtualTerminalLevel"=dword:00000001
```